# How to change color of UIButton for some time interval

Tags: ios, uibutton

How to change UIButton Color for some time interval Like 5-6 sec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this:

```
  [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor coloryouneed]];
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
  [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor previousColor]];
```

Answer (score 6):

Follow thease steps:

1. Add 2 images to your resource folder (say red and blue).
2. Drag a button on XIB, change its property to custom button, and set its background image (to blue.png).
3. Do this in `viewDidLoad` method:

   ```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(changeColor:) 
                                  userInfo:nil 
                                   repeats:NO];
   ```
4. Implement this method:

   ```
   -(void)changeColor:(id)sender
   {
       [btnTemp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"] 
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
   }
   ```

This is the good way that found.

Comment: i tried this first time it is working fine but when i second time not working at all....

Comment: A minor caveat: if you need to repeat the effect, move the `NSTimer` setup to an appropriate method. Otherwise, this is **the** correct way to do such things.

Answer (score 2):

create property of NSTimer in .h file than write below code in .m file

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(changebtncolor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    }

    return self;
}
```

now u can change color in changebtncolor method

Answer (score 1):

You NSTimer. Set a color to button. `[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`.
Schedule a NSTimer to reset it.

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(resetColor) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a thread which changes the color. By using `sleep(randomValue);` you can make your interval.